# Switching a bone's head and tail

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I was trying to set up IK on a model I'm using for animation, when I noticed the foot was trying to bend the hip rather than the knee:
[image]

[image]

I think this is because the thigh bone is facing the wrong way (the head should be at the hip, and the tail should be at the knee).  If that is what is causing this problem, is there a way I can switch the head and the tail without deleting the bone?  If that isn't the problem, what is the problem I am having and how do I solve it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  For anyone trying to figure this out in the future, select the bone in edit mode, press w, and click switch directions.

Comment: for me the shortcut is Alt+F in object mode for switching direction, armature > [switch direction](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/editing/switch_direction.html)